# Just as significant an impact

Tags: phrases, expressions, complex-sentences

What is meant by phrase "just as significant an impact?

I can't understand this sentence:

> Video games had just as significant an impact on popular culture, from Fort nite invading schools across world to Nintendo Direct livestreams.

Comment: It's a shortening of _had an impact on popular culture that was just as significant_ (as whatever impact was discussed before this sentence). The relative clause is chopped up and channeled into a pre-noun modifier "had just as significant an impact". Note that this precedes the indefinite article in the NP, a sign that something has been done to jazz up the object, preceding the list of examples. The clause was chopped and channeled because the list of examples was gonna take up the end of the sentence. Too much information, too little sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think I must be getting something right here! Apparently we were both writing the same "non-inverted / original" version at the same time!

Comment: Great minds, eh?

Comment: @JohnLawler - I think you  mean "grate minds" (;

Comment: @JohnLawler: Nice of you to say so, but whereas I'm feeling justifiably honoured / flattered at finding myself so closely aligned to a true professional, I'm afraid you're slumming it a bit! Actually, no - that's a bit disingenuous. I don't care much about formal grammar as taught in schools, but I do like your constant focus on what people *actually **say*** (as opposed to what they *should **write***). Only a couple of hours ago I listened to John Cleese saying he thought it was a bit odd that he had an English teacher at school (since he figured he already spoke English perfectly well! :)

Comment: @JohnLawler, thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

OP's example is a trivial "inversion" from the more common sequence whereby the relevant *object **noun*** ("an impact", here) comes closer to the relevant ***verb*** ("had", here)...

> *Video games had **an impact** on popular culture [that was] just as significant...*

It's entirely a stylistic choice exactly what order to present the object noun and its associated adjectival element ("just as significant", here). That choice doesn't affect the *meaning* in any way. Nor does it make any difference whether the optional "relativizer" ***that was*** is included or not.

---

EDIT: It's worth including this comment as posted by [Araucaria - Not here any more](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/117625/araucaria-not-here-any-more) in the chat room that OP associated with this question...

> "[**just as significant**] an impact" can also be thought of as a version of "**a** [just as significant] **impact**". This preposing of the adjective phrase is licensed by the deictic adverb **as**. Other such adverbs/quantifiers include **so, that, this** or the combination of [**adjective + enough**].

Comment: Thanks for great explanation.

Comment: @fev: I think you created a *private* chat room that I can't post into without your explicit authorisation. The answer is that your first version is "acceptable", the second is common / natural, and the last one is non-idiomatic. To make it clear exactly what point you're making, the "follow-on" sentence might be better if you include a "focusing" adverb: *He made every effort to **actually** improve* (as opposed to simply "stop getting worse").